# Conditional nested array element in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Here is the function that simplifies the [formatting of console outputs](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-styles-and-formatting-to-your-console-log-messages-in-javascript-5f14819b1c5d):

```js
function generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput(
    formattedOutputData: Array<[string, { [CSS_Key: string]: string; }]>
): Array<string> {

    const outputContents: Array<string> = [];
    const CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent: Array<string> = [];

    for (const singleFormattedOutputData of formattedOutputData) {

        outputContents.push(`%c${singleFormattedOutputData[0]}`);

        let CSS_Declarations: string = "";

        for (const [ CSS_Key, CSS_Value ] of Object.entries(singleFormattedOutputData[1])) {
        CSS_Declarations = `${CSS_Declarations}${CSS_Key}: ${CSS_Value};`;
        }

        CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent.push(CSS_Declarations);
    }

    return [ outputContents.join(""), ...CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent ];
}
```

Now we can make the formatting output as:

```
console.log(...generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput([
    [ " Red bold ", { background: "red", color: "white", "font-weight": "bold", "border-radius": "4px" } ],
    [ " Blue italic", { color: "blue", "font-style": "italic" } ]
]));
```

What if we want to add the conditional element in `generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput([])`?
The basic approach is:

```js
[  "RequiredElement", condition ? [ "ConditionlaElement" ] : [] ]
```

Here, we have the TypeScript error:

```js
console.log(...generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput([
    [ " Red bold ", { background: "red", color: "white", "font-weight": "bold", "border-radius": "4px" } ],
    [ " Blue italic", { color: "blue", "font-style": "italic" } ],
    ...mockCondition ? [ [ " Teal ", { color: "teal" } ] ] : []
]));
```

```
Type '(string | { color: string; })[]' is not assignable to type '[string, { [CSS_Key: string]: string; }]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2322)
```

But the compiled JavaScript works:

[image]

My mistake or TypeScrirpt bug?

[Fiddle](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQYQQGc4AbVAWVSgAs4ATABWxwFtqsiAxOTHzVrjz0A8iCgAHcQAoAsAChESxMF6CowsZPEARXNgBciAIKYcATwA8AbSJRMMMMgA0iAN6Jr+AMreA+gDSqOZGdg5OALqh9o7IANyIAL4RAHwKAJRGphaWYbEp7goKyogQxFCIcOJSUIRgePVEWWbYVnlOBQC8nhFxxcplYHaIPv46qBCkLLjwQ-wAotgQNHUNUM057chdPX3y-UqqmIjSg8NEseT86prVuvqVwCpqQqiid1B6UNjphfuKJWUVW0tQQayIADopEQaNIAAYAUggABI3BcnFcXho3loal9sNYAAwRRJw9J7A6A8gVUZ+caTaawYjRcLIRDdABEHIpAMBz2Op3KnhGvkCwVctIAathSCBUIgIo9ECIAEYAKwmUAh6BiqCI0nRyExAle7xB+OsAEYIulfm5KSVafSpjgmUN2Yg4ainRMXTNiIlvaKguZEkYg-5pbLUIk4nC9nylIkirzAT6Ga7ZtxeItlqsdVCQDDpOm-W6iOTKcn-iVMNQQJgkNZKh9840IWq4I5pFz0q4IQPS4yswsliswTqFXtqymzhVWHAIABrOr0GBuowquBkVDYJDdexynkKM47iGkODIaQDiFoDCugjEHdUWgMZhsDiYbN8LG3EHSaxKWbDlEAAJTeRAt1IehEA5VwPBVJYl2QTAqjAegjA5Ot6Dg0oyF4TCAHcaHXVBcI5VR6gAWkI1AYGQGgoA5TCoJw1wOS3TB6CwKicDXItmNggAWCQAA8QMSBVnCA2DEAAIWjRB1xlGAIFwjwygvTAWOjcjKKgKi7HMchBI5ZTSFUiSpMpG8F2XVd11mRAAH5hWAxAABVd1IWD4LwrTMLwGUrMVRUjGsCIFBtckgA)

Comment: Also: this is legit a function I would use, please make this into a library!

Comment: @LoganDevine, the library is exists, but the documenting of it will take a lot of time. This function available as `printFormattedErrorLogToConsole` protected static method of `AbstractFrontEndLogger` class of `hikari-es-extensions@0.0.32`. (The usage is `import {AbstractFrontEndLogger} from hikari-es-extensions/BrowserJS`). Sorry for not available yet documentation...

Comment: @LoganDevine, sorry for keep you waiting. This functionality has been realized and [documented](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Documentation/BrowserJS/Logging/BasicFrontEndLogger/BasicFrontEndLogger.md#generateconsolemethodparametersforformattedoutput-generating-of-the-formatted-console-output), but the library has been renamed to [`@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions`](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions). I am very sorry if  you don't need it anymore.

Comment: TYSM for that! I'll use it in my next project.

Comment: @LoganDevine, I am glad about it will help you. Please feel free to open the issues. I also will try to apply for the creating of `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions` tag in StackOverflow because I have not enough reputation to create it myself. But if it will be created I'll watch for the new questions with this badge and answer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

In the expression `...mockCondition ? [ [ " Teal ", { color: "teal" } ] ] : []`, the type inferred for the result of the ternary condition will be `(string | { color: string; })[]` (a generic, infinite array) instead of `[string, { [CSS_Key: string]: string; }]` (the tuple type). This is because the expression is not calculated at compile time, so it's resultant type can/doest not be "matched" with function's parameters' types.

### Solution

Use type assertion.

```js
type OutputData = Array<[string, { [CSS_Key: string]: string; }]>
// ^^^^^ declare type here

function generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput(
    formattedOutputData: OutputData
): Array<string> {

    const outputContents: Array<string> = [];
    const CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent: Array<string> = [];

    for (const singleFormattedOutputData of formattedOutputData) {

        outputContents.push(`%c${singleFormattedOutputData[0]}`);

        let CSS_Declarations: string = "";

        for (const [ CSS_Key, CSS_Value ] of Object.entries(singleFormattedOutputData[1])) {
        CSS_Declarations = `${CSS_Declarations}${CSS_Key}: ${CSS_Value};`;
        }

        CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent.push(CSS_Declarations);
    }

    return [ outputContents.join(""), ...CSS_DeclarationsForEachContent ];
}


declare const mockCondition: boolean


console.log(...generateConsoleMethodParametersForFormattedOutput([
    [ " Red bold ", { background: "red", color: "white", "font-weight": "bold", "border-radius": "4px" } ],
    [ " Blue italic", { color: "blue", "font-style": "italic" } ],
    ...(mockCondition ? [ [ " Teal ", { color: "teal" } ] ] : []) as OutputData // type asssertion
]));
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w18Q8W)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanations!